# Post data in Objective C using Json

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, post, nsurlconnection

I am trying to post data to a PHP web service.
I am familiar doing this in html using query $.post but I am very much stumped trying this in objective C.
I tried several blogs & questions found on stackoverflow.

I finally came up with the following code:

```
NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"Email\":\"%@\",\"FirstName\":\"%@\"}",user,fname];
NSLog(@"Request: %@", jsonRequest);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:myurl..."];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];

NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I also tried:
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

My web service creates a new user on post and returns the userID.
Both successfully make the web service call(a new userID is created), however they do not post the data, i.e. a blank user is created every time.
Please tell me if I am missing anything.

Thanks.

My other attempts:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = 
[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:
 [NSURL URLWithString:@"myUrl.. "]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *postString = @"Email=me@test.com&FirstName=Test";

[request setValue:[NSString 
                   stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postString length]] 
forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];

[request setHTTPBody:[postString 
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] 
 initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I finally solved the issue:
  FInally, figured out what was wrong. I was using http://mypath?params=123 as my url. I did not gig the complete url(never needed it in other languages). But here I needed to give htt://mypath/index.php?params=123

Comment: is your server working correctly?

Comment: yes very much.. As i mentioned in my question, I do this very successfully using jquery. Also, in this case using Objective C the server responds with a userID, just does not accept the data that I posted.

Comment: If I create a dictionary like 
    NSMutableDictionary *parms = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [parms setObject:[email text] forKey:@"Email"];
    [parms setObject:[firstname text] forKey:@"FirstName"];
    [parms setObject:[lastname text] forKey:@"LastName"];
would there be a way to convert it to NSData & post it? Would that work better instead of posting JSON string?

Comment: @Praneeta : Pls post your solution as answer.. its working perfectly with me too :) thanks

Answer (score 42):

I think you would be better off using the NSJSONSerialization class like this:

```
NSDictionary *tmp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     email, @"Email",
                     fname, @"FirstName",
                     nil];
NSError *error;
NSData *postdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tmp options:0 error:&error];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Using a dictionary and then converting it to JSON it's easier than creating it like a string.

Good luck!

[**SWIFT 3.0**] (update)

```
let tmp = ["email": email,
           "FirstName": fname]
let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: tmp, options: .prettyPrinted)
request.httpBody = postData
```

Comment: Thanks , figured out what was wrong. I was using http://mypath?params=123 as my url. I did not gig the complete url(never needed it in other languages). But here I needed to give htt://mypath/index.php?params=123

Comment: Thanks.but is there any way we can generate the 'tmp' dictionary simply, in a complex json object. generate the correspond dict is bored..ex:{"user":{"id":"18888888888","pass":"12345678",...},"animal":{"code":{"id":1,"code":123456},"key":true}} to generate the dict making me bored.

Comment: Wasn´t working for me until added header: 

`[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

I have run your code, and server side receive all message.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: linux-test
User-Agent: demoTest/1.0 CFNetwork/548.1.4 Darwin/11.3.0
Content-Length: 44
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Language: en
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive

{"Email":"test@test.com","FirstName":"test"}
```

And follow code, if `jsonRequest` has Non-ASCII characters， the `[jsonRequest length]` will be wrong.

```
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];
```

You can use `strlen` instead.

```
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:strlen([jsonRequest UTF8String])];
```

or

```
[jsonRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: well for some reason my server side code does not like my posted data, I'll look into this tomorrow. Thanks for confirming that my code posts data.

Comment: **if the JSON has Non-ASCII charactersthe [jsonRequest length] will be wrong.**

 - yeah, that is a big gotcha! thanks for the info - I have just spent 2 days debugging a bad request.. all looked fine from the  ipad where I was getting the raw JSOn , then posting the service using a different client that all worked... JSOn looked great, had to use wireshark to see the actual data being received at the WS was being cut short

Comment: @looyao I tried both options you gave still i'm setting same error. Can you please help me some idea. Data i'm trying to send is {"prefferedName":"eivFEGX5pXWBGoqNNtF3og==","nameOnCard":"eivFEGX5pXWBGoqNNtF3og==","macID":"m2/ZIJ5pUB37EnF3tmvdtOnozUeOk+iAM82i2Z0nDEFVsc69vqUXNltN6R2dj7nz","expiryDateMonth":"XAcdf3HTEn3pb2TlWQKHHA==","appVersion":"e6NpxcXU34gHeOyowJbWFQ==","cardNumber":"7qYGPbnqgAMwMJ2GoCEGF4neQanULztzvblT873xj4o="}

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
NSData *requestData = [jsonRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@posts", SeverURL]];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"content-type" value:@"application/json"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"User-Agent" value:@"iOS"];

request.allowCompressedResponse = NO;
request.useCookiePersistence = NO;
request.shouldCompressRequestBody = NO;
request.delegate=self;
NSString *json=[[self prepareData] JSONRepresentation];//SBJSON lib, convert a dict to json string
[request appendPostData:[NSMutableData dataWithData:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

[request startSynchronous];
```

Comment: I had a simular problem with JSON request. I don't know why but adding User-Agent:iOS fixed my problem.