# Map View of other users in your area who have downloaded the app IOS

Tags: ios, location

How can I code into my app so that I can see a map view of all the users who have downloaded the app in my area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of a complex question for being only one sentence. But I'll give it a go:

You need to have an app itself. When a user downloads the app, you need to [get the user's location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11334031/1857279).

You then need to [upload the user's location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15307605/1857279) to a server. Likely, you'd do something like a `POST` request.

But, to be able to upload the user's location, you'd have to have somewhere to receive, store, and process the information. You'd need a [backend server](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20482/how-to-choose-the-best-backend-provider-for-your-ios-app-parse-vs-stackmob-vs-appcelerator-cloud-and-more) for this.

Then, you'd want to be able to send a `GET` request to get a list of the locations that are the closest to the user's location. You'd get back a JSON object.

Here, you'd want to parse through the result and populate an array with `MKAnnotations`. Then you'd add those annotations to a [map view](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-drop-a-pin-on-map-with-mapkit-api/).

It's all very doable, but requires multiple steps inside and outside of your app.