# how to pass the custom headers and get the data from the server using post method (JSON)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios9

below i've shared some PHP code, Iam struck in the passing the custom headers and creating the $message and $header in objective-c. so please help me out in this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQzHr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your image

```
 POST for posting data to SERVER  

-(void)postDataToServer
{
  //STEP 1 :Create the MutableURL Request
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.rgsgapp.com/api/debug/show"]];


 //STEP 2 :create the Method "POST"
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

 //STEP 3 :Pass The String to server(YOU SHOULD GIVE YOUR PARAMETERS INSTEAD OF MY PARAMETERS)
 NSString *userUpdate =[NSString strin gWithFormat:@"API-ID=%@&API-TIME=%@API-HASH=%@",txtFldID.text,txtFldTime.text,txtFldHash.text,nil]; //Here you can give string or textField value

 //STEP 4 :Check The Value what we passed
 NSLog(@"the data Details is =%@", userUpdate);

 //STEP 5 :Convert the String to Data
 NSData *data1 = [userUpdate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 //STEP 6 :Apply the data to the body
 [request setHTTPBody:data1];

 //STEP 7 :Create the response and Error
 NSError *err;
 NSURLResponse *response;

 //STEP 8 :send synchronous request to server  
 NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

 //STEP 9 :getting the response 
 NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

 //STEP 10:Check whether we got the Response or Not
 NSLog(@"got response==%@", resSrt);
 if(resSrt)
 {
   NSLog(@"got response");
 }
 else
 {
   NSLog(@"faield to connect");
 }
}
```

Call this above method in your action method or where you want to do.

Comment: Please tick my answer because it helpful for others,if they see your question.

Comment: Above this is the very basic synchronous method for posting data to server.

Comment: Okey  I will help you.What did you understand from above my answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364156/how-to-post-uitextfield-data-in-web-service-on-unbutton/33365242#33365242

Comment: Kindly step by step go through my answer.

Comment: Especially this line -  NSString *userUpdate =[NSString strin gWithFormat:@"API-ID=%@&API-TIME=%@API-HASH=%@",txtFldID.text,txtFldTime.text,txtFldHash.text,nil]; //Here you can give string or textField value

Comment: But in your image it shows,3 parameters API-ID,API-TIME,API-HASH

Comment: see if you give three parameters with url after that it is not possible to send another parameter with url.